# How to say not an empty string in MYSQL with Regular Expression

Tags: mysql, regex

I am wondering how could i say **not an empty string** in MYSQL with Regular Expression.

My thought :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` <> '^$'
```

I am totally newby as far as Regular Expressions are concerned. And not a pro at all in MySQL.

Comment: Did you take a look at the manual?

Comment: why do u need regex for it? just `WHERE 'column' <> '';`

Comment: `^.+$` will match one or more characters. That being said, I would recommend to sticking to some of the answers below.

Comment: @Robert `WHERE 'column' <> '';` wont do cause this statement will be a part of series of imploded and exploded arrays being cut and added in various combinations.

Comment: @StefanosVakirtzis but these implode arrays will return string still which may be empty and <> '' is going to check it.

Comment: @Robert `column <> ''` doesn't work because it is not true for values that are one or more spaces. ie when `column = ' '`, `column <> ''` is false (trailing spaces are ignored, making the two values "equal")

Comment: string with spaces is not empty :) you should mention it in question. Your question is about the string which has more than one character that is not space. it can be done with TRIM() function `WHERE TRIM(`column`) <> ''`

Comment: Well forgive me for not being able to express my question with 100% precision. And also sorry for not being able to explain why `column <> ''` wont work based on the fact that i am not a pro with MySQL.

Comment: It's okay. Good you have found the answer :)

Comment: To anyone reading these comments:  The above discussion is confused as to whether a string containing nothing but blanks should or should not be considered "empty". The accepted answer considers such strings to NOT be empty - which is consistent with the technical definition for empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `LENGTH()`:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(column) > 0
```

This (correctly) returns rows that are one or more spaces, and doesn't return nulls.

---

Note that

```
WHERE column <> ''
```

behaves differently. `<>` ignores trailing spaces, so a column that contains (only) spaces will be considered the same as `''`, so such rows will be *excluded* from the selection. If that *is* what you want, then you can either do:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column <> ''
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(column)) > 0
```

Either way, a column containing `NULL` will evaluate the WHERE expression to NULL, which will exclude the column from the selection. (It is not necessary to also do "AND column IS NOT NULL")

Comment: This actually works , thank you very much for your help. I will accept the answer in 5 minutes. :)

Comment: Perhaps it was me downvoting by mistake. I will change this when time wise i am eligible to do so. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on whether you want columns containing only blanks to be considered "empty".

To consider blanks to be empty, and *exclude* them from the selection, do:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` <>  '' AND `column` IS NOT NULL
```

NOTE: `TRIM(column)` is **not needed** here, because `<>` *ignores trailing blanks*. However, if you feel that `TRIM(column)` makes the intent clearer, there is no harm in including it:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE TRIM(`column`) <>  '' AND `column` IS NOT NULL
```

This has exactly the same result as the first version.

---

To consider blanks to **not** be empty, and *include* them in the selection, use [Bohemian's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21729219/199364).

---

If you really want use REGEX you should check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEX '^$' AND `column` IS NOT NULL
```

But I don't recommend using REGEX for checking if string is empty.

---

**UPDATE:**
In all of the above answers, `"AND column IS NOT NULL"` *could be omitted*. A column containing `NULL` will evaluate the WHERE expression to NULL, which will exclude the column from the selection.

So the same result can be obtained with the simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` <>  ''
```

Comment: -1 your first answer will not return rows where `column` is a series of spaces - see comment to question.

Comment: @Bohemian sure but it wasn't mentioned in question. It was in comments after I posted my answer.

Comment: but a series of blanks is not the empty string, no matter the comments. it's in the first line of the question in bold!

Comment: My answer doesn't check series of blanks it checks if string is empty. If string contains spaces then it's not empty and this is what the bold part of question is about. At least in my opinion.

Comment: You have just edited the query to add `trim()`, which fixes the error.

Comment: @Robert - this answer is wrong, and it was wrong before you added `TRIM`.; adding TRIM had **no effect**.  You misunderstood Bohemian's objection (and he was wrong when he said that adding TRIM fixed it). String comparison IGNORES blanks, even without the trim. Example: `SELECT LENGTH(SS), (LENGTH(SS) > 0), (SS <> ''), (TRIM(SS) <> '') FROM ...` returns `3, 1, 0, 0` given SS containing 3 ASCII blanks. To anyone else reading this: Use this answer if you want to **exclude** columns containing only blanks. [Sorry, can't change my downvote now - decided that was unjustified, given the confusion.]

Comment: Edited answer to clarify when to use this answer, when to use Bohemian's answer. After editing it, was able to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a comparison to regular expression:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` <> '^$'
```

This is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEX '^$'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` RLIKE '^$'
```

One of the first things in learning about regular expressions is when to use them and when not to.  This is a case not to.  You should just do:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` <> ''
```

By the way, all of these comparisons automatically fail when the value is `NULL`.  If you want to allow `NULL` values, you would have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
fieldname REGEXP '^$|^[[:blank:]]+$|^[[:space:]]+$' OR fieldname IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it